I have a question about the Hebrew Bible being trustworthy?
I ask this because I’m a non-believer who wants to be a believer of G-d and his scriptures. The problem I’m having is that the Hebrew Bible was written mostly by unknown authors and the supposed authors only wrote half of the books, for example the book of Isaiah.
The book that Isaiah supposedly wrote only written half of it and the rest was written by 3 unknown authors and the Torah was mostly written by unknown authors.
Moses and Joshua only wrote a small part of the Torah and the other thing that’s odd is that the authors that wrote most of the Torah didn’t even knew Moses. What I’m asking is how trustworthy is the Hebrew Bible since it was mostly written by unknown authors and how should we trust what they wrote in the most holy of holy books?

"Moses and Joshua only wrote a small part of the Torah"... The premise of your question is wrong

Ok may I ask how?

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Your question is based on information which you might have found in courses on comparative religion or Biblical Criticism. Much of such information is not a fact but hypothesis of the non-Jewish scholars who have agenda to discretit the Jewish tradition. Christians invested in such "studies" because it validates the New Testament claims. For refutations of these claims please read either the book by Joshua Berman Ani Maamin https://www.amazon.com/s?k=joshua+berman+ani+maamin&adgrpid=1343603773622316&hvadid=83975474863908&hvbmt=be&hvdev=c&hvlocphy=58292&hvnetw=o&hvqmt=e&hv

We believe that Moshe wrote the entirety of the Torah (with the possible exception of the last eight verses).
As for the books of the other prophets, we believe they were written by the prophets themselves or later prophets.
See Bava Basra 14b for a detailed list of each book’s authorship.

Thank you for the link you sent I just read half of it and it seems helpful so far. Again thank you.
